# Is there any possibility to use query builder in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, query-builder

I'm currently working in angularjs with html in that I need to use query builder in angularjs. I googled it for that but I can't get any clear idea about that. Is there any possibility to use query builder in angularjs.

Comment: You should be able to use the JQuery plugin perfectly fine together with angular - http://querybuilder.js.org/

Comment: What do you mean by "query builder" ? Is it a facility to issue XHR requests ?